Why does the non-sigmoid transformed output match the target matrix more closely than the sigmoid-transformed output in binary classification?
I am working on a binary classification task using a neural network where the model outputs logits which are then passed through a sigmoid function to map them to probabilities. The target matrix is a 17x17 grid where cells within a Manhattan distance <=2 from the center are labeled as 1 (positive class), and all other cells are 0 (negative class):
Target Matrix
And here's the code for loss. I use binary_cross_entropy_with_logits as my loss function. The sigmoid function is implemented in the mentioned function provided by pytorch:
def forward(self, input, target):
    pos_mask = (target == 1) 
    neg_mask = (target == 0) 
    pos_num = pos_mask.sum().float() 
    neg_num = neg_mask.sum().float() 
    weight = target.new_zeros(target.size())
    weight[pos_mask] = 1 / pos_num 
    weight[neg_mask] = 1 / neg_num * self.neg_weight 
    weight /= weight.sum() 
    return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        input, target, weight, reduction='sum')

Then I visualized the output of the trained model and noticed an unexpected phenomenon. The visualization shows two images: one of the logits directly output by the model (left) and another of the probabilities obtained by applying the sigmoid function to these logits (right). Surprisingly, the non-sigmoid-transformed output (logits) seems to better match the pattern of the target matrix compared to the sigmoid-transformed output (probabilities).
Visualization
This result is puzzling because during training, the loss function operates on the sigmoid-transformed probabilities. Thus, one would expect the sigmoid-transformed output to more closely resemble the target matrix.
Could there be an explanation or a common reason behind this behavior where the raw logits visually match the target structure more accurately than the probabilities derived from them? Are there any visualization or scaling factors I might be missing that could influence this appearance?
I've searched for the internet but there seems no similar questions to mine. And I double check the existence of sigmoid function in the binary_cross_entropy_with_logits:
labels = self._create_labels(responses.size()) 
loss = self.criterion(responses, labels) # criterion: binary_cross_entropy_with_logits

_responses = torch.sigmoid(responses) 
_loss = self._criterion(_responses, labels) # criterion: binary_cross_entropy

However, loss equals to _loss in my experiment, which means that although it is the sigmoided response who tries to fit the target matrix, the non-sigmoided response fits the target matrix better.

If you want more details about the project, here's the description. I'm reproducing an object tracking project with SiamFC, visualizing the response map at line 171 in siamfc-pytorch/siamfc/siamfc.py, as the response map reflecting the similarity between groundtruth target in the first frame and the searching region in the following frames. You can download the pre-trained model in the project, insert some code for visualization and run the code to see the result.
